# Why should the extension of Lax's operator give harmonic functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

I'm reading over Peter Lax's paper [On the existence of Green's functions](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-04/S0002-9939-1952-0051380-0/S0002-9939-1952-0051380-0.pdf).  He gives an argument that is roughly as follows:

> 1. The space $B'$ of continuous functions $\phi$ for which the equation
>      $$\left\{\begin{align*}
>     \Delta u = 0 &\text{ in } \Omega\\
>      u(x) = \phi(x) &\text{ on } \partial\Omega
>    \end{align*} \right.$$
>      admits a classical solution is a closed subspace of $B = C^0(\partial \Omega)$.
> 2. The operators $L_x: B' \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi \mapsto u(x)$ are bounded (by the Maximal principle), so Hahn-Banach lets us extend them to operators on $B$.
> 3. Now, let $N(x)$ be the fundamental solution to the Laplace equation in the whole space.  Then, $N(\cdot - x_0) \in B$ for $x_0 \in \Omega$.
> 4. The function $G(x_0, x) = N(x - x_0) - \psi(x_0,x)$ is then the Green's function, where $\psi(x_0,x) = L_x N(\cdot - x_0)$.

I'm having trouble understanding why the function $\psi$ should be harmonic in $x$.  A priori, it's not even clear that the function $x \mapsto L_xf$ should even be continuous in $x$ for arbitrary $f \in B$, much less satisfy the mean value property.

Does this argument actually show that Green's functions exist?  Or do we need some other argument (like Perron's method)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this paper proves the existence of Green's function (hence the title), and it doesn't depend on e.g. Perron's method.

Harmonicity of $\psi$ (in original, $k_P$) is also explained there. Here, the argument is that the operators $\Delta_{x_0}$ and $L_x$ commute when applied to $N(x-x_0)$. To see this, you should first apply the difference quotient operator 
$$ v(\cdot) \mapsto \frac{v(\cdot+h e_i) - v(\cdot)}{h}, $$
see that this commutes with $L_x$ and pass to the limit $h \to 0$.

Once this is done (and we know $\Delta_{x_0} \psi(x_0,x) = 0$), one only needs to check that $G(x_0,x)$ has zero boundary conditions, in other words, 
$$ N(x-x_0) - \psi(x_0,x) \to 0 \quad \text{when $x$ is fixed and } x_0 \to \partial \Omega. $$